# PHP won't listen to set max_input_vars

Tags: php, ini

Even though I have changed `max_input_vars` in the folder it should listen to, it still says `max_input_vars` is 1000.

According to phpinfo, it listens to 1000. It also says the config file it listens to is `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`. If I open up this file, it says this:

```
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
; max_input_vars = 5000
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are the semicolon in the file?

Comment: The semi-colons are comments - those lines are never read and executed.